# Finding square centers from a picture

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, detection

After an Image Processing, from fft's, filters, and thresholding, I obtained the following image:

[image]

So, I'm wondering how to extract those centers. Does exist any function from OpenCV? (such as HoughCircles for detecting circles?) or Do I need to use clustering methods?

Maybe it is useful for you to know the code I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage 
from scipy.ndimage import maximum_filter

img = cv2.imread("pic.tif",0)

s = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(img))

intensity = 20 * np.log(np.abs(s))
maxs = maximum_filter(intensity, 125)
maxs[maxs < intensity] = intensity.max()

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(maxs.astype('uint8'),0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
imshow(thresh)
```

PS: So I have another question, it could be useful for some of you. The `maximum_filter` function gave me the "3 squares"(then I'll get a better visualization of them by using thresholding), so is there a way to use the `maximum_filter` function and to obtain "3 circles"? Then we can use `HoughCircles` to obtain the 3 centers circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use [Image Moments](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html).

As the pre-processing steps, [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) the source to create mask of squares, and then pass to [findcontours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html).